# bring circle to top on mouseover with d4.v4

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I am working on angular4 and using bubble circle of the d3.v4 graph. I want to show circle at the top(Like to use z-index) on mouseover to that particular circle.

I am using below code in HTML:

```
<svg width="600" height="600" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" text-anchor="middle"></svg>
```

In component.ts file using code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

    var format = d3.format(",d");
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

    var pack = d3.pack().size([width, height]).padding(1.5);
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);


    var root = d3.hierarchy({children: this.data})
    .sum(function(d:any) { return d.value; })
    .each(function(d:any) {
        if (id = d.data.id) {
            var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
            d.id = id;
            d.package = id.slice(0, i);
            d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
        }
    });

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack(root).leaves())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d:any) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("circle")
    .attr("id", function(d:any) { return d.id; })
    .attr("r", function(d:any) { return d.r; })
    .style("fill", function(d:any) { return color(d.package); })
    .on("click", function(d:any) {

        console.log("on click get data: " + d.id);

    })

    .on("mousemove", function(d:any) {

        //console.log("on mouse over get data: ",this);
        // d3.select(this).moveToFront();
        var circle = d3.select(this);
        circle.transition().duration(500)
        .attr("r", function(d:any) { return d.r*2; })

        div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html(d.id)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d:any) {
        //console.log("on mouse out get data: ",this);
        var circle = d3.select(this);
        circle.transition().duration(500)
        .attr("r", function(d:any) { return d.r; })

        div.transition()
         .duration(500)
         .style("opacity", 0);
    })

    .selectAll("tspan")
    .data(function(d:any) { return d.class.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g); })
    .enter().append("tspan")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d:any, i:any, nodes:any) { return 13 + (i - nodes.length / 2 - 0.5) * 10; })
    .text(function(d:any) { return d; });
}
```

I referred below link:

```
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269
```

But Not able to do mouse over. Help me, guys. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moving the circle over other circles, you need to re append it (refer [here](http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/4e0a69d57d3bfc8a82c2)):

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {  
      return this.each(function(){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
      });
    };
```

Then add (mouseover/mouseout) listener to the node group like this:

```
  d3.selectAll(".node").on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).moveToFront();//bring to front
        var circle = d3.select(this).select("circle");//select the circle in the group
        circle.transition().duration(500).attr("r", d => d.r*2)     
        })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        var circle = d3.select(this).select("circle");
        circle.transition().duration(500).attr("r", d => d.r)     
        });
```

Working code [here](https://bl.ocks.org/cyrilcherian/75e64e3179adb7b5328f35b083339e9a/77731b702fc077ef173bf6e6b7c0936765a787d9)

Comment: Thanks for your attention @Cyril.
    I already tired with this, but it's not working. The circle is not coming at the top from others. It is showing popup top based on data. Eg. We have data1, data2, data3. It is showing based on how the data is coming. Even When I do mouseover, the text inside the circle is also getting clear. Please give me another solution. And also I am using version 4. i.e: d3.v4

Comment: @rohit13807 the solution i have posted also uses v4. There must be something wrong on your code, which is leading to incorrect results, please make sure it is close to the solution i have linked in the answer. Other wise may be you can post a working example, i can have a look then.

Comment: I posted my code file. Please have a look: 
     http://66.235.194.119/bubble-circle/bubble.component.ts

Comment: Please, check the example i have posted...you are attaching the listeners on the circle(the listener need to be attached on the group), that is the reason why the text is going behind the circle.
`d3.selectAll(".node").on("mouseover", function(d)`

Comment: Thanks, @Cyril. For Issue: the text is going behind the circle, is solved, But still, the circle is not showing at the top of all others when we do a mouseover.

Comment: Make `var circle = d3.select(this)` to `var circle = d3.select(this).select("circle")` inside the mouse move and mouseover function. see here https://bl.ocks.org/cyrilcherian/75e64e3179adb7b5328f35b083339e9a/77731b702fc077ef173bf6e6b7c0936765a787d9

Comment: Thanks, Great @Cyril. It's working. Actually, I was place code at the wrong place.

Comment: ma you add the imports? how did you install d3?